# itemRenderer is cancelling wordWrap setting on DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flexbuilder

have a question.

Now, I created two codes. 
The code of （１） is displayed correctly. 
However, as for the code of （２）,doesn't wrap.

（１）

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" dataProvider="{mounth}" width="100%" height="100%" variableRowHeight="true"  wordWrap="true">   
            <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header1" wordWrap="true">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:Text  text="aaaaaaaaaaa" width="100%" height="100%" />
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
    　　　　　</mx:columns>        
</mx:DataGrid>
```

（２）

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid2" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" dataProvider="{mounth2}" width="100%" height="100%" variableRowHeight="true"  wordWrap="true">   
        <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header2" wordWrap="true">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                               <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
                            <mx:Button label="btn"/>
                            <mx:Text id="userNameb" text="bbbbbbbb" width="100%" height="100%" />
                        </mx:HBox>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
　　　　　</mx:columns>       
</mx:DataGrid>
```

I want to use a button and a text into HBox by itemRenderer. 
And　I want to make it wordrap and to display.

Please tell me someone.

---

Thank you !
Your figure is intelligible!

It corrected to the passage of (3). 
The text wraps once it reaches that width.

(3)

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid2" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" dataProvider="{mounth2}" width="100%" height="100%" variableRowHeight="true"  wordWrap="true">   
        <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header2" wordWrap="true">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                               <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
                            <mx:Button label="btn"/>
                            <mx:Text id="userNameb" text="bbbbbbbb" width="120" height="100%" />
                        </mx:HBox>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
　　　　　</mx:columns>       
</mx:DataGrid>
```

May I ask a question by addition? 
I want to display a character according to the width of DataGridColumn of DataGrid.

Is there how to display by variable length? 
Incidentally (1) is displayed by variable length.

Comment: just try: give static height to `Hbox` `height="50"` instead `100%`

Comment: I tried code 1 and it doesn't wrap...

Comment: I want to display a character according to the width of DataGridColumn of DataGrid. ----> just have the same width to `DataGridColumn` and `HBox` and `Text` that is `width="120"`

Answer (score 0):

Like M.S.Nayak noted in their comment, you have to set an explicit width for the component you want to wordwrap so that the text wraps once it reaches that width[image]